# CDI producer method not working if defining class doesn't declare a scope

Tags: java, cdi, glassfish-4, java-ee-7, weld

I'm running some proof of concept in a local Glassfish 4.1.1 (WELD 2.2.2) installation about CDI.

I've created a class bean named TipicalBean which injects an integer produced in a producer method.

The class defining the producer method looks like this

```
public class ProducerTest {

    @Produces @MyNumber @Dependent public static int getMyNumber() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Even if I declare the method **static**

But it does work if if put the @Dependent scope in the class definition, like this:

```
@Dependent
public class ProducerTest {
```

In addition, if I declare that producer method in the same class which is injecting it, I can define the @Dependent scope in the producer method declaration, but WELD prints a warning in Glassfish console

```
WELD-000018: Executing producer field or method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces
@MyNumber @Dependent public mypackage.TipicalBean.produceMyNumber() on incomplete
declaring bean Managed Bean [class mypackage.TipicalBean] with qualifiers [@Any
@Default] due to circular injection
```

Why's that? Is that Producer Methods must be defined within ManagedBeans?

As I'm using JavaEE 7, I have not created the beans.xml file.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your `beans.xml`, you are probably lacking the `bean-discovery-mode="all"`.

Comment: I haven't created any beans.xml file, since I'm using CDI 1.1. I haven't found any reference to that behaviour in reference to producer methods among documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#producer_method):

> A producer method must be a default-access, public, protected or
>   private, non-abstract method of a managed bean class or session bean
>   class.

Comment: And to clarify, your class wasn't being registered as a managed bean because the lack of `beans.xml` put your environment into `bean-discovery-mode=annotated` and your no bean defining annotations, it had nothing to do with scope (though scopes are a bean defining annotation)